# Is calling twice onreadystatechange on a function possible?

Tags: javascript

I have a XMLHttpRequest defined like this:

```
sub_opt=function()
{
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
var data = new FormData();
...some stuff to complete data
xhr.open( 'post', 'PHP/write_and_exec_opt.php');
var display_opt=xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 ) {
                text=xhr.responseText.trim();
....some stuff
    }
xhr.send(data);
return xhr;
}
```

this function was called by another function where xhr is stored as a global var for the js file under the name previousRequest.
While the request is processing the user can do other stuff but I need some of the stuff he may have initialized to stop once the request is over. Thus I put in the necessary place the following part:

```
var stop_refresh=previousRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (previousRequest.readyState == 4 ) {
clearInterval(refresh);
        }};
```

to be called when the same request is over.
The problem is that if I put only one of the onreadystatechange it works fine but with the two only thelast one work. 
Is it not allowed to do what I am trying?

Thank for advices.

Comment: Did you try with promises ? It vaguely looks like your async stuff could use some promises ("but I need some of the stuff he may have initialized to stop once the request is over").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that onreadystatechange is a property of an object.

When you set it, you are overwritting previous values. This is not the same than when you add two different listeners to same object, allowing different handlers to fire on a single event.

In this way, when you change the onreadystatechange property, you totally overwrite the previous value.

You'll need to tinker with your functions and namespacing to fix your problem.